# Run php script in FTP without knowing public http address

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I need to zip and extract the database from a host. I created 2 php scripts for this but the problem is that i cannot execute them from browser because i don;t know the public path. That's because this is an old hosting i had but surprisingly i still can connect to FTP with the details i had. Since the domain is no longer associated with this hosting i can't find the public path.

My question is, having the ftp access, is there any way i could execute those 2 scripts to zip the entire folder and download the database (i also have the mysql details). I tried logging through SFTP with WinSCP and running the Execute custom command however no success.

Thank you so much, i really don't have any ideas what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options, 
1 If you have ssh access, execute 
php yourscript.php

2 If you have remote mysql access, you can export your sql via a mysql client like sequelPro, etc

Comment: Doh, i already have SQLyog for WIN and will try now, haven't thought of that, great suggestion. As for SSH don't have access. Thanks for the help!!